# CI/CD Deployment Using Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

i have my springboot-rest api application. I have created Web app, CI and CD pipeline successfully.But after successful deployment if i am hitting deployed app service URL i am not able to see my application.Please find the attached screen shots for different steps. Can anyone tell me what i need to do to see my application running.

Below image link is successful deployment of CI/CD Pipeline.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgmME.png

Following image i am getting after hitting deployed App Service URL. If i am hitting deployment center it is showing successful deployment to App service. But i am not able to see my restful endpoint is running.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPXpF.png

i also tried with endpoint which i use to hit with postman and able to get output. Following is post man URL.

http://localhost:8080/vodafone/api/v1/azure/createProject?clientName=HexawareTechnologiesLtd&ticketNo=RITM0010739&location=southindia

My App Service Deployment URL is.

http://vmmigrateapp.azurewebsites.net

If i am hitting same URL with Postman using this URL i am getting 404 error.

http://vmmigrateapp.azurewebsites.net/vodafone/api/v1/azure/createProject?clientName=HexawareTechnologiesLtd&ticketNo=RITM0010739&location=southindia

Comment: Can anyone please at least some idea or suggestion. its urgent and critical.

Comment: please give me at least suggestions.i am stuck.

Comment: Have you checked the deploy log? Is there any useful information? Also, are you able to see the deployed files in the app service?

Comment: I checked inside app service the jar was present. JAR inside app service was present under /home/site/wwwroot# folder.

Comment: Do i need to add any additional  configuration in pom.xml.

Comment: Could you please try to add the app name in the link to see whether you can access it, like http://vmmigrateapp.azurewebsites.net/appname? You can check the app name from Kudu console. To access the Kudu Console, navigate to `{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net`, and click on `Debug Console`: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console.

Answer (score 0):

App service needs JAR to be named as app.jar. Only JAR with app.jar name can be executed in azure app service. So Please add app in POM.xml file under  section. This will generate JAR with name app.jar. By default it generate projectname+version as JAR name which can't be run in azure app service.After doing this project can be build and deployed using Azure CI/CD and run by app service.